# los permisos y grupos que asigno a mi usuario personalizado en django >= 3.1 no sirven

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

estoy intentando adentrarme en la administración de django, he creado mi propio usuario personalizado como me ha guiado la documentación oficial y he creado mi propio usuarioAdministrador para registrarlo correctamente en django admin o administrador de django, todo funciona bien hasta que intento asignar permisos a un usuario o asignar un usuario a un grupo, los usuarios al final terminan teniendo todos los permisos.
los archivos dentro de mi aplicacion navecomClient son :
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import  BaseUserManager,AbstractBaseUser, Permission, Group, 
PermissionsMixin

class usersManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email,tipo_usuario,no_documento, nombre, apellido, no_celular, tel_fijo,direccion, barrio, referencia_vivienda, nickname, estado, password):
        usuario = self.create_user(email = email, no_documento = no_documento , nombre = nombre, apellido = apellido, no_celular = no_celular, tel_fijo = tel_fijo,direccion = direccion, barrio = barrio, referencia_vivienda = referencia_vivienda, nickname = nickname,  tipo_usr = tipo_usuario, estado = estado, password = password)
        usuario.usuario_administrador = True
        usuario.save()
        return usuario

    def create_user(self, email, tipo_usr,no_documento, nombre, apellido, no_celular, tel_fijo,direccion, barrio, referencia_vivienda, nickname, password, estado ):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('el usuario debe tener un correo electronico')
        else :
            usuario = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email),no_documento = no_documento , nombre = nombre, apellido = apellido, no_celular = no_celular, tel_fijo = tel_fijo,direccion = direccion, barrio = barrio, referencia_vivienda = referencia_vivienda, nickname = nickname, estado = estados_usuario.objects.get(pk = estado),  tipo_usuario = tipo_usuario.objects.get(pk=tipo_usr))
            usuario.set_password(password)
            usuario.save()
            return usuario

class usuario(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tipo_usuario = models.ForeignKey(tipo_usuario, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_ty_us')
    no_documento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=0, null=True, db_column='document_usr')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='f_name')
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='l_name')
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    no_celular = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, null=True, db_column='cell_number')
    tel_fijo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True, db_column='phone')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, db_column='address')
    barrio = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column='neighborhood')
    referencia_vivienda = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column='home_reference')
    fecha_cumpleaños = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, db_column='dob')
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    token_key = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=True, null = True, db_column='register_date')
    estado = models.ForeignKey('estados_usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='state_usr', null = True)

    usuario_administrador = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = usersManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [ 'tipo_usuario','no_documento', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'no_celular', 'tel_fijo','direccion', 'barrio', 'referencia_vivienda', 'estado', 'nickname' ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.usuario_administrador

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        app_label = 'navecomClient'
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import *

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmar contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = usuario
        fields = ('email', 'password','tipo_usuario','no_documento', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'no_celular', 'tel_fijo','direccion', 'barrio', 'referencia_vivienda', 'nickname', 'estado','usuario_administrador', 'groups')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    
        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = usuario
        fields = ('email', 'password','tipo_usuario','no_documento', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'no_celular', 'tel_fijo','direccion', 'barrio', 'referencia_vivienda', 'nickname', 'estado','usuario_administrador', 'groups')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, PermissionManager
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import *
from .forms import *

# Register your models here.

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    model = usuario

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'tipo_usuario')
    list_filter = ('estado','tipo_usuario')
    fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('nickname', 'tipo_usuario', 'estado', 'usuario_administrador')}),
    ('Informacion personal', {'fields': ('email', 'no_documento', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'no_celular', 'tel_fijo','direccion', 'barrio','referencia_vivienda', 'password')}),
    ('Permisos', {'fields': ('groups', 'user_permissions' )}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'tipo_usuario','no_documento', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'no_celular', 'tel_fijo','direccion', 'barrio', 'referencia_vivienda', 'estado', 'nickname', 'password1', 'password2', 'usuario_administrador', 'groups','user_permissions'),
    }),
    #('Permisos', {'fields': ('groups','user_permissions')}),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email','estado')
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register( usuario, UserAdmin)

admin.site.register(monto_adicional)
admin.site.register(lista_montos)
admin.site.register(facturas)
admin.site.register(categorias_servicio)
admin.site.register(contrato)
admin.site.register(estados_cliente)
admin.site.register(cliente)
admin.site.register(lista_descuentos)
admin.site.register(descuentos)
admin.site.register(empleado)
admin.site.register(novedades_plan)
admin.site.register(metodos_pago)
admin.site.register(estados_plan)
admin.site.register(plan)
admin.site.register(solicitudes_servicio)
admin.site.register(servicio)
admin.site.register(tipo_usuario)
admin.site.register(estados_usuario)
admin.site.register(Permission)
```

y en el archivo setting de mi proyecto:

settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'admin_interface',
'colorfield',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'navecomClient.apps.NavecomclientConfig',
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'navecomClient.usuario'
```

cuando creo usuarios desde el administrador de django y los asigno a grupos y permisos y me logueo con esos usuarios siguen teniendo todos los permisos sobre todos mis modelos.

imagen de la creación de un usuario desde el administrador de django. asi seleccione algunos permisos o asi seleccione un grupo al crear el usuario no se les aplica esos cambios.

gracias.

[image: imagen de la creación de un usuario desde el administrador de django:]

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi.
no me percate de estos dos metodos en mi modelo de usuario en el archivo models.py

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

simplemente hay que quitarlos supongo que es porque esto siempre devuelve verdadero